# Python - ModuleNotFoundError- No module named 'XXX'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have folder hierarchy as:

```
->Project Folder
  -Main.py 
  ->modules Folder
    ->PowerSupply Folder
      - PowerSupply.py
      - SerialPort.py
```

In `Main.py` I am importing `PowerSupply.py` with following command

`from modules.PowerSupply.PowerSupply import *`

Then inside of `PowerSupply.py`, I am importing SerilPort.py with following command

`from SerialPort import SerialPort`

So, when I try to run the Main.py, PowerSupply.py throw an error in the line `from SerialPort import SerialPort`. The error is

```
"Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'SerialPort'"
```

When I modify the `PowerSupply.py` as
`from modules.PowerSupply.SerialPort import SerialPort`, it is not throwing error. But it don`t seem like a good way to me. Is there any way to solve this error?

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files in your folders? I don't see them in your example, but they are critical

Comment: @MikeL, AFAIK, they are not that critical anymore since Python 3.3 (due to the introduction of [namespace packages](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/)

Comment: @MikeL I dont have any  __init__.py files.

Comment: I added __init__.py files. But, nothing changed

Comment: Camon, it's better to include this information in your question than to answer in comments. (And you can surround the filename with backticks, so it's rendered as `__init__.py`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Powersupply.py try explicit relative import:

```
from .SerialPort import Serialport
```

"*When I modify the PowerSupply.py as
from modules.PowerSupply.SerialPort import SerialPort, it is not throwing error. But it don`t seem like a good way to me. Is there any way to solve this erro*r"

Note that according to PEP 8 absolute imports (which your solution is) are actually preferred: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports

Answer (score 1):

Well described here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

When importing modules, you need to stick to hierarchy.
If `modules` folder is part of hierarchy, you cannot skip it.
You could solve it with adding `PowerSupply` folder to Python search path.